# CQL query in Cassandra with composite partition key

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3

My main problem is with paginating Cassandra resultset on a table with a composite partition key. However, I am trying to narrow it down with a simple scenario. Say, I have a table,

```
CREATE TABLE numberofrequests (
  cluster text,
  date text,
  time text,
  numberofrequests int,
PRIMARY KEY ((cluster, date), time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time ASC)
```

And I have a data like,

```
 cluster | date       | time | numberofrequests
---------+------------+------+------------------
      c2 | 01/04/2015 |   t1 |                1
      c2 |         d1 |   t1 |                1
      c2 | 02/04/2015 |   t1 |                1
      c1 |         d1 |   t1 |                1
      c1 |         d1 |   t2 |                2
```

Question: Is there any way I can query data for cluster=c2? I don't care about the 'date' and honestly speaking I keep this only for partitioning purpose to avoid hot-spots. I tried the following,

```
 select * from numberofrequests where token(cluster,date)>=token('c2','00/00/0000');

 select * from numberofrequests where token(cluster,date)>=token('c2','1');

 select * from numberofrequests where token(cluster,date)>=token('c2','a');

 select * from numberofrequests where token(cluster,date)>=token('c2','');
```

My schema uses the default partitioner (Murmur3Partitioner). Is this achievable at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra needs the partitioning key (PK) to locate the queried row. Any queries based only on parts of the PK will not work, since its murmur3 hash won't match the hash based on the complete PK as initially created by the partitioner. What you could do instead is to use the `ByteOrderedPartitioner`. This would allow you to use the `token()` function as in your examples by keeping the byte order of the PK instead of using a hash function. But in most cases, that's a bad idea, as data will not be distributed evenly across the cluster and you'll end up with hotspots you tried to avoid in first place.

Comment: It's worth adding you can have in clustering key some kind of bucket instead of date, for example day of week. Therefore all data would spread through "cluster" and the day of week. To retrieve those data you would fire 7 requests for one cluster.

Comment: Hmm. Initially I was having the impression, that the token() function is an alternative in non ByteOrderedPartitioner schemas, to range query partition keys. However, I believe it is not. When I went through CQL 3.3 docs now, it mentions that "results will not always be consistent with expectations". I will accept your answer as the correct answer. Now I keep wondering what good is the token() function for!

Comment: The `token()` function is the only way to work with partition key ranges. Using something like `where cluster > 'c2' and date > '00/00/0000'` is simply not possible as only equals comparison is allowed for conditions on the PK.

Comment: No, I don't think token() will work correctly, as I have mentioned above. And I was not mentioning a where clause like what you are saying. I know it is not possible.